# How to get direct sum decomposition of a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

If S is the space of (0,3)-tensors such that $s_{XYZ}-s_{XZY}$ and if the action of the pseudo-orthogonal group O(m,n) is given by $(as)_XYZ=s_{a^-1Xa^-1Ya^-1Z}$, $a\in$O(m,n) then $S=S_1\oplus S_2\oplus S_3$. Here

$S_1$ is the set of tensors such that $s_{XYZ}=<X,Y>\omega (Z)-<X,Z>\omega(Y)$, $\omega \in V^*$,

$S_2$ the set of tensors such that $\Sigma_{XYZ}s_{XYZ}=0$, $c_{12}(s)=0$, $c_{12}(s)(X)=\sum_i\epsilon_is_{e_ie_i}X$, $\{e_i\}$-an orthonormal basis, $<e_i,e_i>=\pm 1$,

$S_3$ is the set of tensors such that $s_{XYZ}+s_{YXZ}=0$.

My question is how to get these spaces $S_1$, $S_2$ and $S_3$. In general, is there a pattern we need to follow in obtaining direct sum.
I can understand if we decompose space by using linear transformation, but here I can not find a connection between the given action and the obtained subspaces nor to find references in which the explicit calculation is given.

Answer (score 1):

See, there is an algorithm  to get the Direct sum of a vector space

Given a Vector Space and one of its subspace there always exist a subspace which is the direct complement of the Vector Space w.r.t to that given subspace.

Now, the proof that it exist gives us the algorithm to find it out.

1. Take a Vector Space V and a Subspace S of it.
2. Take a basis of S say B.
3. Extend B to a basis of V say M.
4. Take span(M/B) which is the direct complement of V w.r.t S say K.
5. For further direct sums like 3 or more.
    Apply the same algorithm on the same on K taking one of its subspaces.

Hope it helps.If you have any problem regarding the explanation please feel free to ask.